# Loop through names of DataFrames to drop dups and group by and create new DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I have several data frames. I'm trying to perform three actions on them, dropping duplicates and then doing a group by on two columns and getting size of a third column, and then creating data frames from each of these two steps. I'm getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
DF_NAMES_LIST = ["DF1", "DF2", "DF3"]

For x in DF_NAMES_LIST:
    x_2 = x.drop_duplicates("var1", "var2", "var3")
    x_3 = x_2.groupby(["var", "var2"]).var3.size()
```

The code works for individual DFs outside the loop, but when I run the loop I get:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'
```

Any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are looping over names of the data frames,  not the data frames themselves.   The names are just strings,  they don't have any group_by or drop_duplicates methods.  You should loop over the actual data frames
like this:

```
DF_NAMES_LIST = [DF1, DF2, DF3]

for x in DF_NAMES_LIST:
   x_2 = x.drop_duplicates("var1", "var2", "var3")
   x_3 = x_2.groupby(["var", "var2"]).var3.size()
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I tried that but am getting this error now ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type str.

Comment: I tried adding inplace = True nafter "var3" in the first step but it says too many arguments

Comment: I needed two parentheses around drop_duplicates. That fixed it. Thanks!